# Is it possible to make a property required, yet preserve undefined

Tags: typescript

I've tried removing the optional modifier with `-?` but it appears to treat `undefined` and optional as the same thing:

```
interface Props {
  firstName?: string | undefined;
  lastName?: string;
}

// Built-in
// type Required<T> = {
//   [P in keyof T]-?: T[P];
// };

type RequiredProps = Required<Props>;

// EXPECT:
// { firstName: string | undefined; lastName: string; }

// ACTUAL:
// { firstName: string; lastName: string; }
```

The following question is very similar, however (there is a clear  the accepted answer implies the ques

#### Similar but different questions

[How to prevent `Required<T>` in typescript from removing 'undefined' from the type when using --strictNullChecks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57324324/how-to-prevent-requiredt-in-typescript-from-removing-undefined-from-the-ty)

Question sounds similar, but they don't give a clear expected input / output and the accepted answer doesn't result in the expected output I've defined above. e.g.

```
interface Props {
  firstName?: string | undefined;
  lastName?: string;
}

type RequiredKeepUndefined<T> = { [K in keyof T]-?: [T[K]] } extends infer U
  ? U extends Record<keyof U, [any]> ? { [K in keyof U]: U[K][0] } : never
  : never;

type RequiredProps = Required<Props>;

// EXPECT:
// { firstName: string | undefined; lastName: string; }

// ACTUAL:
// { firstName: string | undefined; lastName: string | undefined; }
```

Comment: They do behave differently https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPIhQbwFDOTYKAZzADk4BbCALmRKlAHNkAfZAVxABMICMuA3NgC+2bKEixEKACoB3APbIceAsTKUIAflr0mQ0dgQKQJZHFroUAXmXChRk2YBGteUtuZ72IA

Comment: How about using `null` instead of `undefined`?

Comment: You may find an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57324324/how-to-prevent-requiredt-in-typescript-from-removing-undefined-from-the-ty

Comment: Also discussion on https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31025

Comment: Yeah I'd seen that question and it seems they're asking for the same thing, however the accepted answer suggests otherwise because `RequiredKeepUndefined<Props>` returns `{ firstName: string | undefined; lastName: string | undefined; }` - https://shorturl.at/puFX3

Comment: Then please [edit] to show that research, and explain how the existing answers don't solve your use case.

Comment: Are you looking for the exactOptionalPropertyTypes compiler option?

Comment: @catgirlkelly Yes! That's exactly what I'm after https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgApQPYAcDOyDeAUMsjMFDmAHJwC2EA-AFzKVSgDmyAPsgK4gAJhDIgIggNzFkAGziUa9ZqzDsQHKQF9ChAPS7kAIT7AZYALSg9BsAE8sKAEoQAjiajiAPABUAfMgBeAmsSZABtVGRQZABrCFsMGGRvAF1zZW8IlKl9ZE0pQjsHZGc3cnF0bDwg0vcvStxfAtyAUQANVBaAYW8mEPxScgU6CBY2Th5+IRFQcQlZeWoRsdVOee0QgEEegFVNgBk+3NRNgGVTwiA 

I've never seen that configuration before; I'm guessing it's probably not widely used, but should be good for my current needs. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`exactOptionalPropertyTypes`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#exactOptionalPropertyTypes) compiler flag to tell TypeScript to disallow assigning `undefined` to optional properties. This also has the effect of treating `T | undefined` in an optional property *as literally* `T | undefined`. Previously, it would've just been `T`.

Here their example shows:

```
interface UserDefaults {
  // The absence of a value represents 'system'
  colorThemeOverride?: "dark" | "light";
}

const settings = getUserSettings();
settings.colorThemeOverride = "dark";
settings.colorThemeOverride = "light";
 
// But not:
settings.colorThemeOverride = undefined;
// ^ Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type '"dark" | "light"' with 'exactOptionalPropertyTypes: true'. Consider adding 'undefined' to the type of the target.
```

And it works as you can see [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgApQPYAcDOyDeAUMsjMFDmAHJwC2EA-AFzKVSgDmyAPsgK4gAJhDIgIggNzFkAGziUa9ZqzDsQHKQF9ChAPS7kAIT7AZYALSg9BsAE8sKAEoQAjiajiAPABUAfMgBeAmsSZABtVGRQZABrCFsMGGRvAF1zZW8IlKl9ZE0pQjsHZGc3cnF0bDwg0vcvStxfAtyAUQANVBaAYW8mEPxScgU6CBY2Th5+IRFQcQlZeWoRsdVOee0QgEEegFVNgBk+3NRNgGVTwiA), it makes `firstName` the type `string | undefined` instead of just `string`.