# How to make all keys of a type required while keeping undefined as possible value?

Tags: typescript

I want to map key/values of a type as follows:

- `required_key: string | undefined` to `required_key: string | undefined` (same)
- `required_key: string` to `required_key: string` (same)
- `optional_key?: string | undefined` to `optional_key: string | undefined` (removed ? from key)
- `optional_key?: string` to `optional_key: string | undefined` (removed ? from key and added undefined as possible value)

```js
interface Person {
  firstName: string | undefined;
  middleName?: string;
  lastName?: string | undefined;
}

// What I need:
// interface Person {
//   firstName: string | undefined;
//   middleName: string | undefined;
//   lastName: string | undefined;
// }

type Normalize<T> = { [K in keyof T]-?: T[K] };

// What I get with Normalize<Person>:
// interface Person {
//   firstName: string | undefined;
//   middleName: string;
//   lastName: string;
// }

const test: Normalize<Person> = {
  firstName: undefined,
  middleName: undefined, // ts err, type = string, undefined not allowed
  lastName: undefined, // ts err, type = string, undefined not allowed
};
```

Is it possible in typescript? It seems that `-?` is removing undefined from both key and value and I don't know how to add undefined value option if key is optional.

I read this Q/A [Is it possible to make a property required, yet preserve undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72402413/is-it-possible-to-make-a-property-required-yet-preserve-undefined) and I know about `exactOptionalPropertyTypes` compiler flag but it still does not solve how to convert `key?: string` to `key: string | undefined`.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mZ1a9N) meet your needs?  Test against your use cases and if it works for you I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is the best solution, but you can achieve it with the following:

```js
type AllOptionalKeys<T> = { [K in keyof T]-?: undefined extends T[K] ? K : never; }[keyof T];
type AllNonOptionalKeys<T> = { [K in keyof T]-?: undefined extends T[K] ? never : K; }[keyof T];

type Normalize<T> = { [K in AllOptionalKeys<T>]: T[K] | undefined } & { [K in AllNonOptionalKeys<T>]: T[K]; };
```

The two intermediate types allow to strip the `?` from the keys, but keep track of which are optional.

Then it constructs an union type, where all optional keys have a value of `T[K] | undefined`, and all the non optional keys have `T[K]`.

Comment: Perfect thank you! It even works without `exactOptionalPropertyTypes` compiler option.

Comment: I think the option from @jcalz in the comment of your question is better though :D