# Typescript: Required<T> does not remove '| undefined' from properties of T (strictNullChecks=true)

Tags: typescript, typescript-utility

Because of the following [sentence in the typescript doc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#example-6) I thought that `Required<T>` will also remove `| undefined` from all properties of Type `T` as long as strictNullChecks are activated.

> Note that in strictNullChecks mode, when a homomorphic mapped type removes a ? modifier from a property in the underlying type it also removes undefined from the type of that property:

I also find [stackoverflow Posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57324324/how-to-prevent-requiredt-in-typescript-from-removing-undefined-from-the-ty) that have problems because of the removed `undefined`.

Unfortunately I don't see this behavior.

**The problem**

`?` is removed but `| undefined` is not.

Example:

```
interface Entity1 {
    optionalVal?: string | undefined;
}
type CompleteEntity1 = Required<Entity1>
```

VSC tells me on mouseover

```
type CompleteEntity1 = {
    optionalVal: string | undefined;
}
```

So

```
const testCompleteEntity1: CompleteEntity1 = {
    optionalVal: undefined  // <== No Error
}
```

I already found a solution that works for me.

```
type RequiredAndDefined<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]-?: Exclude<T[P], null | undefined>
}

interface Entity2 {
    optionalVal?: string | undefined | null;
}
type CompleteEntity2 = RequiredAndDefined<Entity2>

const testEntity2: Entity2 = {
    optionalVal: undefined  // <== No error as expected
}

const testCompleteEntity2: CompleteEntity2 = {
    optionalVal: undefined  // <== Error as expected
}
```

...but I don't understand why I need this (I guess `Required` should be enough to detect `undefined` ?!)

My current tsconfig.json

```
{
  "extends": "@tsconfig/node16-strictest/tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {

    "outDir": "./dist/",

    "lib": ["es2022"],

    "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": false,

    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true                           /* test...to let Required<T> remove '| undefined' from the types of the properties of T (https://stackoverflow.com/q/57324324/7869582) */
  }
}
```

Comment: What if you have exactOptionalPropertyTypes enabled?

Comment: Your problem does not replicate in [the Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKLmGAngRmQbwChkTkB7ABzGDJDgBsA1BgfgC5kBnMKUAc2QAfZAFcQAEwgxQEcQG5CAX0LYKKAMJkAthXoRI6atjwBeZACUIARxHAosgDyHMuAHxA).

Comment: @kelly I also found a solution by setting exactOptionalPropertyTypes but I liked the solution with 'RequiredAndDefined' more.

Comment: @Etheryte hmm, that's unfortunate. Any idea how I can debug my ts config?!

Comment: Hmm, if this isn't reproducible I don't know how we can help.  Those tsconfig options seem fine, I guess? Are you sure you're actually using that ts config?

Comment: I am pretty sure. To test it I have imported and logged a json file. This works when I set 'resolveJsonModule' to true and throws an Error if I set it to false...in exactly this tsconfig.json